# Setting Up CorePlot Crosshair in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, graph, core-plot

I am attempting to create a crosshair (vertical line) for my graph in Swift. I have looked over the various Objective-C examples of how to do this, and have mimicked them in the code below:

```
class viewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var graphView: CPTGraphHostingView!

var plot1: CPTScatterPlot!
var plot2: CPTScatterPlot!
var plot3: CPTScatterPlot!

var plotDataSource1: CPTFunctionDataSource?
var plotDataSource2: CPTFunctionDataSource?
var plotDataSource3: CPTFunctionDataSource?

var markerAnnotation: CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}


override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    initPlot()

}

func initPlot() {

    configureHostView()
    configureGraph()
    configureChart()
    configureAxes()


}

func configureHostView() {
    graphView.allowPinchScaling = true
    print("host con called")
}

func configureGraph() {
    // 1 - Create the graph
    let graph = CPTXYGraph(frame: graphView.bounds)
    graph.plotAreaFrame?.masksToBorder = true
    graphView.hostedGraph = graph

    // 2 - Configure the graph
    graph.applyTheme(CPTTheme(named: kCPTPlainWhiteTheme))
    graph.fill = CPTFill(color: CPTColor.clearColor())
    graph.paddingBottom = 0.0
    graph.paddingLeft = 0.0
    graph.paddingTop = 0.0
    graph.paddingRight = 0.0


    // 3 - Set up styles
    let titleStyle = CPTMutableTextStyle()
    titleStyle.color = CPTColor.blackColor()
    titleStyle.fontName = "HelveticaNeue-Bold"
    titleStyle.fontSize = 16.0
    titleStyle.textAlignment = .Center
    graph.titleTextStyle = titleStyle


    // 4 - Set up plot space
    let xMin = -10.0
    let xMax = 10.0
    let yMin = -10.0
    let yMax = 10.0
    guard let plotSpace = graph.defaultPlotSpace as? CPTXYPlotSpace else { return }
    plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = true

    plotSpace.xRange = CPTPlotRange(locationDecimal: CPTDecimalFromDouble(xMin), lengthDecimal: CPTDecimalFromDouble(xMax - xMin))

    plotSpace.yRange = CPTPlotRange(locationDecimal: CPTDecimalFromDouble(yMin), lengthDecimal: CPTDecimalFromDouble(yMax - yMin))
    print("graph con called")
}


func configureChart() {
    // 1 - Set up the three plots
    plot1 = CPTScatterPlot()
    plot2 = CPTScatterPlot()
    plot3 = CPTScatterPlot()

    // 2 - Set up line style
    let lineStyle1 = CPTMutableLineStyle()
    lineStyle1.lineColor = CPTColor.blueColor()
    lineStyle1.lineWidth = 0.5

    let lineStyle2 = CPTMutableLineStyle()
    lineStyle2.lineColor = CPTColor.redColor()
    lineStyle2.lineWidth = 0.5

    let lineStyle3 = CPTMutableLineStyle()
    lineStyle3.lineColor = CPTColor.greenColor()
    lineStyle3.lineWidth = 0.5

    // 3 - Add plots to graph
    guard let graph = graphView.hostedGraph else { return }

    plot1.delegate = self
    plot2.delegate = self
    plot3.delegate = self

    //let function: CPTDataSourceFunction? = cos
    let block1 = {(x: Double) -> Double in
        return sin(x)
    }
    let block2 = {(x: Double) -> Double in
        return 1/x
    }
    let block3 = {(x: Double) -> Double in
        return log(x)
    }


    //if (block != nil) {
    plotDataSource1 = CPTFunctionDataSource(forPlot: plot1, withBlock: block1)
    plot1.dataSource = plotDataSource1
    //}

    plotDataSource2 = CPTFunctionDataSource(forPlot: plot2, withBlock: block2)
    plot2.dataSource = plotDataSource2

    plotDataSource3 = CPTFunctionDataSource(forPlot: plot3, withBlock: block3)
    plot3.dataSource = plotDataSource3


    plot1.dataLineStyle = lineStyle1
    plot2.dataLineStyle = lineStyle2
    plot3.dataLineStyle = lineStyle3


    graph.addPlot(plot1, toPlotSpace: graph.defaultPlotSpace)
    graph.addPlot(plot2, toPlotSpace: graph.defaultPlotSpace)
    graph.addPlot(plot3, toPlotSpace: graph.defaultPlotSpace)

    print("chart con called")
}

func configureAxes() {
    // 1 - Configure styles
    let axisLineStyle = CPTMutableLineStyle()
    axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0
    axisLineStyle.lineColor = CPTColor.blackColor()
    let majorGridLineStyle: CPTMutableLineStyle = CPTMutableLineStyle()
    majorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.75
    majorGridLineStyle.lineColor = CPTColor.grayColor()
    let minorGridLineStyle: CPTMutableLineStyle = CPTMutableLineStyle()
    minorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.25
    minorGridLineStyle.lineColor = CPTColor.whiteColor()

    guard let axisSet = graphView.hostedGraph?.axisSet as? CPTXYAxisSet else { return }

    // 3 - Configure the x-axis
    let axisStyle = CPTMutableTextStyle()
    axisStyle.fontSize = 6.0

    //
    let crosshair = CPTXYAxis()
    crosshair.hidden = false
    crosshair.coordinate = CPTCoordinate.Y
    crosshair.plotSpace = graphView.hostedGraph?.defaultPlotSpace
    crosshair.axisConstraints = CPTConstraints(lowerOffset: 10.0)
    crosshair.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicy.None
    crosshair.separateLayers = true
    crosshair.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 6
    crosshair.minorTicksPerInterval = 0
    let cStyle: CPTMutableLineStyle = CPTMutableLineStyle()
    cStyle.lineWidth = 4.0
    cStyle.lineColor = CPTColor.orangeColor()
    crosshair.axisLineStyle = cStyle
    crosshair.majorTickLineStyle = nil
    //

    let x: CPTXYAxis = axisSet.xAxis!
    x.labelingPolicy = .Automatic
    x.title = ""
    x.labelTextStyle = axisStyle

    let y: CPTXYAxis = axisSet.yAxis!
    y.labelingPolicy = .Automatic
    y.title = ""
    y.labelTextStyle = axisStyle

    axisSet.axes = [x, y, crosshair]

    let hitAnnotationTextStyle: CPTMutableTextStyle = CPTMutableTextStyle()
    hitAnnotationTextStyle.color = CPTColor.blackColor()
    hitAnnotationTextStyle.fontName = "Helvetica-Bold"
    hitAnnotationTextStyle.fontSize = 6

    let textLayer: CPTTextLayer = CPTTextLayer(text: "Annotation", style: hitAnnotationTextStyle)
    textLayer.cornerRadius = 3.0
    textLayer.paddingLeft = 2.0
    textLayer.paddingTop = 2.0
    textLayer.paddingRight = 2.0
    textLayer.paddingBottom = 2.0
    textLayer.hidden = false

    let graph = CPTXYGraph(frame: graphView.bounds)
    let plotSpace = graph.defaultPlotSpace as? CPTXYPlotSpace
    let annotation: CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation = CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation(plotSpace: plotSpace!, anchorPlotPoint: [0, 0])
    annotation.contentLayer = textLayer
    graph.addAnnotation(annotation)
    self.markerAnnotation = annotation

    print("axes con called")

}
```

}

```
extension viewController: CPTPlotSpaceDelegate, CPTPlotDataSource, CPTScatterPlotDelegate {

func numberOfRecordsForPlot(plot: CPTPlot) -> UInt {
    print("1")
    return (self.plotDataSource1?.dataPlot.cachedDataCount)!
}

func numbersForPlot(plot: CPTPlot, field fieldEnum: UInt, recordIndex index: UInt) -> AnyObject {
    print("2")
    return (self.plotDataSource1?.dataPlot.cachedDoubleForField(UInt(fieldEnum), recordIndex: UInt(index)))!
}

func plotSpace(space: CPTPlotSpace, willDisplaceBy displacement: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    print("3")
    return CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)
}

func plotSpace(space: CPTPlotSpace, willChangePlotRangeTo newRange: CPTPlotRange, forCoordinate coordinate: CPTCoordinate) -> CPTPlotRange? {
    print("4")
    var updatedRange: CPTPlotRange? = nil
    let xySpace: CPTXYPlotSpace = (space as! CPTXYPlotSpace)
    switch coordinate {
    case CPTCoordinate.X:
        updatedRange = xySpace.xRange
    case CPTCoordinate.Y:
        updatedRange = xySpace.yRange
    default:
        break
    }

    return updatedRange!
}

func plotSpace(space: CPTPlotSpace, shouldHandlePointingDeviceDownEvent event: UIEvent, atPoint point: CGPoint) -> Bool {
    print("5")
    let xySpace: CPTXYPlotSpace = (space as! CPTXYPlotSpace)
    let graphy = xySpace.graph!
    let crosshair = graphy.axisSet!.axes![2] as? CPTXYAxis
    var plotPoint = space.plotPointForEvent(event)
    let annotation: CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation = self.markerAnnotation!
    let textLayer: CPTTextLayer = (annotation.contentLayer as! CPTTextLayer)
    var xNumber = plotPoint![CPTCoordinate.X.rawValue]
    var yNumber = plotPoint![CPTCoordinate.Y.rawValue]

    if xySpace.xRange.containsNumber(xNumber) {

        let x: Int = Int(Double(xNumber))
        let y: Int = Int(Double(yNumber))
        xNumber = x
        yNumber = y
        let xValue: String = (graphView.hostedGraph!.axisSet?.axes?[0].labelFormatter!.stringForObjectValue(xNumber)!)!
        let yValue: String = (graphView.hostedGraph!.axisSet?.axes?[1].labelFormatter!.stringForObjectValue(yNumber)!)!
        textLayer.text = "\(xValue), \(yValue)"
        textLayer.hidden = false
        annotation.anchorPlotPoint = [xNumber, yNumber]
        crosshair!.orthogonalPosition = xNumber
        crosshair!.hidden = false

    } else {

        textLayer.hidden = true
        crosshair!.hidden = true

    }

    return false
}

func plotSpace(space: CPTPlotSpace, shouldHandlePointingDeviceDraggedEvent event: UIEvent, atPoint point: CGPoint) -> Bool {
    print("6")
    return self.plotSpace(space, shouldHandlePointingDeviceDraggedEvent: event, atPoint: point)
}

func plotSpace(space: CPTPlotSpace, shouldHandlePointingDeviceUpEvent event: UIEvent, atPoint point: CGPoint) -> Bool {
    print("7")
    return false
}


}
```

The data I am trying to index is created from a CPTFunctionDataSource, so what I am trying to do might be more complicated. Any assistance is appreciated...

Comment: What is your question? Which part isn't working as expected?

Comment: @EricSkroch This code, which is in my ViewController, does not work--which is to say I can see my crosshair axis line, but it doesn't respond to touch or show an annotation

Comment: Is the pointing device down method called when you touch the plot space?

Comment: @EricSkroch When I compile and run my code, none of these functions are called, for some reason (I checked with a print() command)... If the code itself, especially in numberForPlot and numberOfRecordsForPlot, looks correct, then is it a class problem?

Comment: Make sure the plot `datasource` and plot space `delegate` are set correctly.

Comment: @EricSkroch Putting all the code you see above in a viewController extension with the class as so: `extension viewController: CPTPlotSpaceDelegate, CPTPlotDataSource, CPTScatterPlotDelegate {` still does not work

Comment: Did you set the plot `datasource` and plot space` delegate` to the view controller during the setup process? Please edit the question and include the rest of your Core Plot code.

Comment: @EricSkroch I added the rest of code; also I'm not quite sure what you mean by the last comment

Comment: 1. You're using a `CPTFunctionDataSource` to supply plot data so you don't need to implement `numberOfRecordsForPlot()` or `numbersForPlot()` at all. The function datasource provides its own implementations of the plot datasource methods.

Comment: 2. Why do you set the plot `delegate`? I don't see any plot delegate methods implemented. It won't hurt, but its unnecessary.

Comment: 3. You need to set the `plotSpace.delegate` to the class that implements the delegate methods (`self`?). You can set it in `configureGraph()` with the other plot space setup.

Comment: @EricSkroch Some of the irrevlant things you saw were leftover from other attempts I had made to get the code working. I just made the changes you suggested in point 3, and now the event methods are being called but the crosshair 'axis' still does not move--also drag events for the plot range do not work anymore

Comment: @EricSkroch I got the axis to move, although it's only changing position (in the x domain) at integer steps--is there a way to move the crosshair at an arbitrary precision?

Comment: You're using an integer `orthogonalPosition` for the crosshair axis. There's no reason it has to be an integer. Same with the annotation anchor—both can be any numeric value.

Comment: @EricSkroch Okay, in that case what is the best way to extract the value of a point on a plot from a CPTFunctionDataSource data source?

Comment: You know the functions used to draw the plots. Find the x-value (without rounding it to an integer) of the interaction and use the function to compute the corresponding y-value. Since you have three plots, you might need some logic to determine which one is closest to the interaction point. Alternatively, all plots have a `-dataIndexFromInteractionPoint:` method. Call it on each plot and use the index to retrieve the plot's cached data for that point. Again, since you have three plots, you'll need to decide which of the plots is closest to the interaction point.

Comment: @EricSkroch Okay awesome I have everything working save two features: 1) is there a way to deselect the crosshair so you can still pan the graph and 2) my annotation is stuck to the bottom of the screen and nothing I code seems to move it...

Comment: 1. Track whether the crosshair is visible or not. In the plot space delegate methods, only modify the ranges, etc. when you want the graph to stay still.  2. Changing the `anchorPlotPoint` of the annotation should move it. Check your calculations for the new anchor point.

Comment: @EricSkroch I think I have it all straightened out now... many thanks!